# Getting out of the Add-Ins window

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I was able to produce an add-in, which provides two user interfaces. However they are shown as tabs in the Add-Ins window. Earlier I worked with a single control and this one has been shown in its own window.

[image]

They both have different GUIDs and are registered COM objects. I initiate like this:

```
control1 = GuiManager.Repository.AddWindow("Quick Interface Editor", "QuickInterfaceEditor.QuickInterfaceEditorControl") as QuickInterfaceEditorControl;
control2 = GuiManager.Repository.AddWindow("Tagged Values Editor", "TaggedValuesEditor.TaggedValuesEditorControl") as TaggedValuesEditorControl;
```

Is there a way to bring both tabs to their own windows? Or at least replace the "Add-Ins" title by my add-in's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically three ways to show a window as an add-in

### Repository.AddWindow()

This adds an add-in window in the add-ins docked window. If this is the only add-in window that uses this section, than the docked window will get the title from the add-in window.
[image]

If there are multiple add-ins, the title will be **Add-Ins** and each add-in will get a tab, like you noticed with your add-ins.
[image]

### Repository.AddTab()

This adds a window to the main diagram space
[image]

### Form.ShowDialog() or Form.Show()

This allows you to show a model dialog, or regular window on top of EA's GUI
[image]

Comment: So not possible :-( But thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @JanRothkegel yeah, I'm afraid so. These are the only options available. Feel free to send a feature request to Sparx. Not that I think they'll do something about it any time soon, but you never know